# How to get over this SXXP0003 parser error?

Tags: xml-parsing, saxon, dtd

I have an XML document which prolog looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
...
```

This XML document is valid against the external DTD with the exact same prolog :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
...
]>
```

When I transform using Saxon (latest release):

```
$:/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/$ java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:pandora.xml -xsl:pandora.xsl -o:pandora.html
```

Error on line 1 column 53 of pandora.dtd:
SXXP0003   Error reported by XML parser: No more pseudo attributes are allowed.: No more
pseudo attributes are allowed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/fred/pandora/dtd/pandora.dtd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 53; No more pseudo attributes are allowed.

I am newbie and my research about this has only led to listing the pseudo-attributes in the order they actually are.  If anybody have a clue there.

**Edit**
I have made other transformations using the same process with other projects without any problem. The only difference is in this problematic application, I make use of another namespace [exsl](http://exslt.org/common) to use a function not provided with version 1.0 (node-set). Everything else is similar.

Comment: Col53 corresponds to the position before the 2nd '?' as the end of the PI.

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about `pandora.dtd` not your XML document.  What does line 1 of `pandora.dtd` look like?

Comment: Exactly as shown, it’s the prolog with the <?xml...?>, col 53 is pointing right before the question mark (and after closing quote of standalone attribute).

Answer (score 1):

For an external subset of the DTD the specification defines the format in https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-extSubset as

```
extSubset ::= TextDecl? extSubsetDecl
extSubsetDecl ::=  ( markupdecl | conditionalSect | DeclSep)*
```

, for the "Text Declaration" in https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-TextDecl as `TextDecl ::= '<?xml' VersionInfo? EncodingDecl S? '?>'` so a `standalone` "pseudo" attribute is indeed not allowed there.

So make sure that your external DTD file does not repeat `<!DOCTYPE root`, it is just meant to contain declaration of markup, e.g. elements, attributes.

The error message you get comes anyway just from the XML parser and is not transformation/XSLT related.

Comment: Thanks for the link, which I tried. Doing so, the error is « the markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well formed ».

Comment: Well, we can't explain errors without seeing the code. Show minimal but complete samples to allow anyone to easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jfo420, also see the edit, if your external .dtd also starts with `<!DOCTYPE root`, you have got that part wrong as well, only put declarations of e.g. elements, attributes, entities in there.